# Play Processing Video From Mouse Coordinates?

Tags: video, processing

I'm trying to make a program to play different videos depending upon where the mouse coordinates are. Basically open up a plain window and move the mouse around and if the mouse coordinate is between a set of numbers, play video number one. Then when the mouse coordinate is between another set of numbers, play video number 2.

I wrote a base code that changes the text depending upon the mouse coordinates. Here's an excerpt:

```
void setup() {
  size(934,887);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
//if x is between 46 and 339 AND y is between 46 and 249, then 1
  if((46<mouseX && mouseX<339)&&(46<mouseY && mouseY<249)){
    textSize(20);
    text("1", width/2, height/2);
  }

//if x is between 46 and 339 AND y is between 249 and 464, then 2
  if((46<mouseX && mouseX<339)&&(249<mouseY && mouseY<464)){
    textSize(20);
    text("2", width/2, height/2);
  }
```

I want to use this same concept but now play different videos instead of displaying different texts. I'm not sure how to go about this because the processing video tutorials I've seen have different void setups and void draws and everything just for playing videos and I don't get how to combine with my own mouse tracking code. Do I need to create multiple windows? And how would that work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the video to continue even if we are watching the other video, it's fairly easy: we load the different video as [Movie](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/Movie.html) objects in the `setup()` method and just let them play in loop while the mouse coordinates dictates which video is currently playing. Here's a code snippet to demonstrate:

```
import processing.video.*;
Movie lightbulbs, sample360;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);

  lightbulbs = new Movie(this, "lightbulbs.mov");
  sample360 = new Movie(this, "360.mov");

  lightbulbs.loop();  // .play(); will play it once, .loop() will start over again after the last frame
  sample360.loop();
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  if (mouseX < width/2) {
    image(lightbulbs, 0, 0);
  } else {
    image(sample360, 0, 0);
  }
  
  // here's a line so we see clearly where the movie changes in the example
  stroke(255);
  line(width/2, 0, width/2, height);
}

void movieEvent(Movie m) {
  m.read();
}
```

To load my movies as easily as possible, I went into the sketch's folder and created a `data` folder. Processing will recognize this folder and whenever you try to load a file without specifying a path, it'll look for it in there (so that's where I saved my sample movies):

[image: data folder]

[image: movies]

The movies weight a little bit more, so I'll let you figure out where to find your own. Peronnaly I just googled "free .mov samples" and picked some at random from there.

For me it went like this (it's resized on the go to make the file lighter):

[image: zapping between channels]

I'll hang around in case you have questions, but I think this would respect your base concept and do the job. Have fun!